# Using Tweepy to get the results from saved searches on Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get the tweets from my saved searches using tweepy with python. I am not super great with Python, but the documentation seems pretty good, however, it is just returning empty lists. I know there are results for the searches because I can load them up in a browser. However, tweepy doesn't seem to see them.

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

saved_searches = api.saved_searches()

for search in saved_searches:
    saved_search = api.get_saved_search(search.id)

    results = api.search(q=str(saved_search.query))

    for result in results:
        print(result.text)
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing here?

Comment: nothing appears to be wrong with your code, at least when I test it with my credentials and my api settings. I had no prior saved_searches, so I initially got an empty list too, but I performed a search via the web interface, checked trough the rest API here, and confirmed the search got saved, then ran your script and got a response of about 15 items. I'm not sure where a problem may exist on your end as I can't reproduce what's missing, but I can confirm your code works for me.

Comment: well that is really good to know. could it be that the saved query is too complicated? the query that i am passing in is 'from:CNNPolitics since:2016-11-01 until:2016-11-08'

Comment: Yes, that may be it, I'm not sure that it is "too complicated" per-se, but I can confirm that if I also save that same query into my saved searches list through the twitter API, then run your script, *now* I also do get an empty string back...though I'm not sure what is causing the empty results. Perhaps something regarding the `results = api.search(q=str(saved_search.query))` is coming back empty. I'd suggest breaking it down line-by-line, and finding which line is returning `None`.